# FBE - Why does each user get a separate DE key

Tags: security

I've been reading about how File-Based Encryption and Direct Boot work. There's one thing I don't understand.

According to https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot

> Device encrypted (DE) storage contains data encrypted with a key that is only available after a device has performed a successful verified boot.

If I understand correctly, if an application stores data in DE areas, that data is available after the device boots up **even prior to any user authentication (i.e prior to the device being unlocked)**.

Then, according to https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based

> Each user in a multi-user environment gets a separate encryption key. Every user gets two keys: a DE and a CE key.

...

> An application may be able to interact freely across the DE areas, but one user unlocked does not mean that all the users on the device are unlocked".

**Question**: If an application has access across the DE areas, what is gained by generating a separate DE key for each user?

**Potential answer**

Initially I assumed that ***user*** in the above quoted sections refers to a *physical user* as described [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user)

> User. Each user is intended to be used by a different physical person.

But ***user*** can also refer to an *application user* as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals)

> The Android operating system is a multi-user Linux system in which each app is a different user.

So I'm thinking:

When an application stores data in DE storage, the data is encrypted using the *application user*'s DE key.

When an application stores data in CE storage, the data is encrypted using the currently active *physical user*'s CE key.

If the above is correct, A *physical user*'s DE key and an *application user*'s CE key is never used.

I don't know if the above makes any sense so it would be great if someone with the appropriate knowledge would chime in.